# Website reloading HTML file in the middle of site loading when defered non-essential CSS file is added. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First the plain HTML with with base64 encoded webp images and internal CSS in the <head loads giving it a first contentful paint as quickly as possible

Then an event listener watches for the complete page load and then loads the external JS file

Then the index.js file is loaded to allow the second half of the website to load under the fold with the defered javascript (Which is what index-cont.html is). It also loads the external CSS file so that the users browser can cache the CSS

However something is going wrong, its starting to load the initial HTML file and then reconnects and loads the SSL file then loads the HTML again. Instead of just going dns>connection>ssl>html like its supposed to.

This is what's going on with my page load

[image]

I have an external JS file that's defered using an event listener.

This is my HTML, I have a base64 @font-face in the file as well that i've omitted for length reasons.

```html
.heading{
    font-family: 'biryaniregular';
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
}
.link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #32378C;
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
}
.divider{
    border: 1px solid #44c1f2;
    }
.header{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}    
.header__logo{
    height: 54px;
    width: 300px;
}
.link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #2573D9;
}
.header__links{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
.left{
    margin:2.5%;
}
.actionbutton:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
  }
.product-box{
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    margin-righT: 2.5%;
}
.product{
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 98%;
    height: auto;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    .container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    }
    .right{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a href="index.html">
            <img class="header__logo" alt="Plushtech Company Logo" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRnoEAABXRUJQVlA4IG4EAABQHACdASosATYAPrVSpE0nJCOiJlEbaOAWiWcA1smoer7sz/gFRG+Mv7F21/5Wu9/1Hjl/kvB3as3Wzj38x/3XhBai/ebW0Y4/+V6hmgH6l9hL9ZOtH+2JiH57srQyRvNqaHTgRpx3JFHMfOPW+JIN0wpLV0veRDW3KnXlavLM2omchAO2SnZtmQ159rqR6kPCDpdtJQQyLN2l2Vpb2wPmDTb+GrMpKX9wreLTrPqJidbxRI7XkAwzFfN5WKEjQ5X6+yWWWMNLNWAmYV2qZFxtafX3tZaHu6DMiXcyz63FDpYV6I9rr6KxfagAAP74TVKp8g8Zvj9d/h3x79qkWeHGec3gD7E0JoSFGe9oSkNyztcrHCPKFveLdrlH+HmtfyWfh2S6e+vYLbOiG09E9opu2km3ORP7Ztm9lUJmYdPku0JFUmVWuUwCEPNOsExiruFNDn/5EmwmjPZmhVzxoZ99Pe/Mf1ZDlBcTPOgOJhsKBIP3YeNZhLOGGXS6nxpOQf14oEAJmBTIl59tscjzKyzUdaPjcYfzihL/+smMC7zU/AdmISr0LR5nMIEjlsNnd1r5xj+JDyW/wheNf/DdA/os3L8HdjpRzdf1aG0oBdiO1U8i5I9/aWmxxEr5DcLpIn++Souy85unXvL4KX0TLMvh+SVFbhGUz5qxyu1H/YytNoNIBEijjXGusaZisNK7Jzhznoz4GCim7KL+qM5JflHQo9Ofxf9ElftecsWVCkuJ/z/dvScRsNvsgf8FHBXPWqADE3LUnVN4/PACdLoMLOkO7NiQfjeUL6d8W7rI4DNx6u7XOOKkUiKIepLM8PVqag5Ju6MZemwpm7wnW35MGIPeqNKcSIMGO3oZX+6SOEUg3EB2hBo0pfHn8bOvL4QubMOt8hJn5V1xvD+8MSPpblEzhOMypn/W5QHQYS/y20lI5Uf156qPgSGNA2mbU4bmkwcdzpURu0wx7PbfCjOf7LM0DZd5IAjA7q4IFjYSqZgp8RVqqcOqETYo2k/BUqHfJPZup8Hn9bzyz/1ofms1Qa/ukTuyHiQT+HjH/T/AioLoTFouz/l9WV0IflTA9LXAviBuTreRRIMEXBPYKgwa75SEOIlKYG/cnQFsS4qgdAHuPWLbwwH49L4+qS2wjAY3nAKS7yGPHxg90NEySb2Muhx1LqzQ5ezJppVOaQJes+5Z0KgcCMxYnn82Q4Qbf85f2q+hg2yzi0N/VdDffy8qf3l+wzGkIqW9L3XBZkPm1r3RHTF8qlk6Rob3hIa4m2r870JbD2LcyuQbzXef7yKDpkvdEzVuEe6xbUfLnKcPholHmeh1PdFsi1uJeaMwU69xkK11WVMl3zBV96ytptC6AgFxB1hD5yHtKMuM9wCq6THQjn+3BvXgJRROcLW82gh2C+vHQK2tM46r9njko18ubfwn/lxCh2FPDhPZ0mCAos74HwCPh4IkNiG6v3Edz0EDwjs6k9mSkR4/C7CXwoRRF5KKupk1RNb0oNIuo+aAAAA=" />
        </a>
        <div class="header__links">
            <h3 class="heading">
                <a class="link" href="customerservice.html">
                     Customer&nbsp;Service</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;<a class="link" href="ordertracking.html">&nbsp;Order&nbsp;Tracking
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
<hr class="divider">
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
            <h1 class="heading">testtestestest</h1>
            <div class="sidemenu">
                <h3 class="heading">
                <a class="link" href="returnpolicy.html">
                    Return Policy
                </a> 
                <h3 class="heading">
                <a class="link" href="shippingpolicy.html">
                    Shipping Policy
                </a> 
                <h3 class="heading">
                <a class="link" href="privacypolicy.html">
                    Privacy Policy
                </a>
                <h3 class="heading">
                    <a class="link" href="aboutus.html">
                        FAQ
                    </a>    
                    </h3> 
                <h3 class="heading">
                <a class="link" href="aboutus.html">
                    About Us
                </a>    
                </h3>
            </div>
    <hr class="divider">        
            
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="product-box">
             <a href="product-page-mobile.html">
                 <img class="product" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRmIAAABXRUJQVlA4IFYAAADwBQCdASpkAGQAPlEokkajoqGhIKgAcAoJaW7hc+lwAAFqwmIv/ljYi8sA11N7iLywDXU3uIvCAAD+/sUX//97Bf+9AP+7Bf7Mf/i2KQ2B3XakcAAAAA==">
             </a>
            <a class="link" href="product-page-mobile.html">
                 <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
            </a>
            <h3 class="heading">11.11</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="product-box">
            <a href="product-page-desktop.html">     
                 <img class ="product" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRmIAAABXRUJQVlA4IFYAAADwBQCdASpkAGQAPlEokkajoqGhIKgAcAoJaW7hc+lwAAFZ2IvLANdTe4i8sA11N7iLywDXU3toAAD+/o5///DlT6dvY//+vR/+ej/89H+cwz06gAAAAA==">
            </a>
            <a class="link" href="product-page-desktop.html"> 
                 <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
            </a>
            <h3 class="heading">11.11</h3>     
        </div>
        <div class="product-box">
            <a href="product-page-mobile.html">        
                 <img class="product" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRmIAAABXRUJQVlA4IFYAAADwBQCdASpkAGQAPlEokkajoqGhIKgAcAoJaW7hc+lwAAFqwmIv/ljYi8sA11N7iLywDXU3uIvCAAD+/sUX//97Bf+9AP+7Bf7Mf/i2KQ2B3XakcAAAAA==">
            </a>  
            <a class="link" href="product-page-mobile.html">  
                 <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
            </a>
             <h3 class="heading">11.11</h3>     
        </div>
        <div class="product-box">
            <a href="product-page-desktop.html">     
                 <img class ="product" src="data:image/webp;base64,UklGRmIAAABXRUJQVlA4IFYAAADwBQCdASpkAGQAPlEokkajoqGhIKgAcAoJaW7hc+lwAAFZ2IvLANdTe4i8sA11N7iLywDXU3toAAD+/o5///DlT6dvY//+vR/+ej/89H+cwz06gAAAAA==">
            </a>
            <a class="link" href="product-page-desktop.html"> 
                 <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
            </a>
            <h3 class="heading">11.11</h3>     
        </div>
    </div>     
</div>
<hr class=divider>
<div class="text" id="indexcont">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "javascript/index.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the external JS file that the above links to

```js
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest && 'ActiveXObject' in window) {
    window.XMLHttpRequest= function() {
        return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttp');
    };
}

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'defered-html/index-cont.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    if (this.status!==200) return; // or whatever error handling you want
    document.getElementById('indexcont').innerHTML= this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();

(function() {
    var cssMain = document.createElement('link');
    cssMain.href = 'css/global.css';
    cssMain.rel = 'stylesheet';
    cssMain.type = 'text/css';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssMain);
})();
```

Anyone know whats going on? I'm trying to load the global.css file last.  first the plain html file should load, then the js, then the index-cont.html, then the global.css

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly your use of XMLHttpRequest() is in my opinion redundant. You
  should take advantage of the Fetch API and Promises.
- Also why not use inline defer on the javascript

And finally is their a reason you wan it in that order because browser resource loading isnt as reliable as you would think

Comment: I'll look into the first two, thank you.

The reason I don't use inline defer is because it doesn't allow the page to completely load until it runs the js. This solution does. 

And yes, its based on user behavior.

On the product page (which i use the same script) there's a certain order that people will be interacting with the website.

When they view a product, the first thing their going to do is look at the images. So the JS for the images needs to load first.

Then their going to scroll down to the below the fold content and look at the additional product info(cont)

Comment: so then the below the fold HTML needs to load.

Then the externall CSS loads so that it can be cached by the browser for the rest of the site

Then the flavicon loads because that's the least importiant.


I know I can do that with promises, but that doesn't explain why the external CSS file is bugging the html before the event listener even loads the external JS file.

Comment: like i said how browser loads resources isn't reliable. You should use Lazy Loading Images using Intersection Observer. This is what u are looking for. You shouldn't rely on the precedence of the loading of resources in your code

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but that wasn't my question. - I'm asking about red circle in the above image

Comment: hmmm..logic thinking 101...when you cant get your desired result try another method...you maybe going about this wrongly try lazy loading. My 2 cents, browser resource precedence loading isnt reliable

Comment: however if u are still interested in this path, you can checkout this:https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization